# Tag merge request: derived-works, derivatives, derivative-works

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

It seems the tags [derivative-works](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/derivative-works), [derived-works](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/derived-works) and [derivatives](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/derivatives) are all used for the same thing. Should the latter two be superseded with the first? Should either of the first two be retained as redirects, or should they just be burniated?

Comment: Adding synonyms would be best.

Answer (score 7):

### Let's keep [derivative-works](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/derivative-works) and make the other two synonyms.

It is the clearest and searchable out of the three. The other two can still function as redirects. If something gets tagged with a synonym, the master tag gets shown anyway.

Comment: I support the idea of synonyms, but I feel that tagging to [derivative-Works] isn't the best, as it retags something that may not be a work to this tag.

Comment: @Zizouz212 that seems like a very obscure use-case, but I'm no expert.

Comment: It may not be common, but it is a possibility. I like the concise tag more, but then of course, voting will take the community opinions. If someone likes mine, then so be it. Likewise with yours.

Comment: I'm just going to play a little devil here... *But that's bad grammar! You should be using [derived-works]!!!* :)

Answer (score -3):

I agree, let's make the tags synonyms.

However, I say let's make the tags synonyms of [derivatives](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/derivatives) as it is a more concise tag. That way, something that is a derivative but not a derivative work will not be automatically retagged to [derivative-work](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/derivative-work).

Tags -> [derivatives](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/derivatives)

Comment: "Derivatives" or "Derivative" is very bad tag for this. It is used in [calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative), [chemistry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_%28chemistry%29) and [finance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_%28finance%29). These meanings has nothing to do with [*Derivative work*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_work) or things that is relevant to our site. As for anything *relevant* that is "a derivative but not a derivative work", I am unable to understand what that should be.

Comment: @FreeRadical Do note, that this is similar to the drm tag discussion meta had earlier, drm is ambiguous, but half the things won't apply to this site. I'm sure that calculus != open source. If we're nervous about ambiguity, then there is also the tag wiki, and tag wiki excerpts.

Comment: What kind of derivatives do you think would be on-topic at the site that aren't derivative works?

Comment: @curiousdannii I'm not entirely sure. I suggested this idea mostly because it was more concise, and it would be another thing for the community to vote on.